# How To Make Data Stop After 30 Seconds?

Tags: android, button, android-sensors

I am currently working on a app that collects data from one of the sensors on the android device. What I would like to happen, is when a button is pressed, the data will display for 20-30 seconds and then pause after that time frame without the user having to press anything.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the usage of Timer or CountDownTimer classes.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Generally.... create an onClickListener on the button that, when the button is clicked, starts the collection of the data AND starts a timer. When the timer expires, stop the collection of data.